# Repainting a dirty region interfere with graphics2D clipbounds

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d

In the following reproducer, I am reproducing what I'm seeing in the graphical interface.
I'd like to repaint a dirty region of a canvas (a `JPanel`), because a full repaint introduces more latencies.

However when the repaint (dirty rectangle) function is invoked, it causes some issues with nested Graphics2D objects. In particular

[image: full repaint]
[image: dirty rectangle/region repaint]

This code may mis-use clip bounds, but I wasn't expecting this "artifact" upon the creation of the sub (nested) graphic context.

What would be the proper way to deal with clips, nested graphic contexts, and the dirty region (or rectangle) `repaint` in this situation.

My intuition tells me the code should compute its shape without using the clipping area.

---

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Reproducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var comp = new MyJPanel();
        var timer = new Timer(2_000, e -> {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(comp::bug);
        });
        timer.start();
        timer.setRepeats(true);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            var frame = new JFrame("Reproducer");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().add(comp);
        });
    }

    private static class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyJPanel() {
            setSize(600, 600);
            setPreferredSize(getSize());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            var g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            super.paintComponent(g2);
            g2.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g2.fill(g2.getClip());

            var graphicsBox = (Graphics2D) g2.create(10, 10, 290, 290);
            var clipBounds = graphicsBox.getClipBounds();
            graphicsBox.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            graphicsBox.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
            graphicsBox.drawRect(clipBounds.x, clipBounds.y, clipBounds.width, clipBounds.height);
            graphicsBox.setColor(Color.red);
            graphicsBox.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(clipBounds.x + 2,
                                                    clipBounds.y + 2,
                                                    clipBounds.width - 2,
                                                    clipBounds.height - 2));
            graphicsBox.dispose();


            var graphicsOverlay = (Graphics2D) g2.create(100, 100, 100, 100);
            graphicsOverlay.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            graphicsOverlay.fillOval(10, 10, 60, 60);
            graphicsOverlay.dispose();
        }

        public void bug() {
            getVisibleRect();
            repaint(100, 100, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT by moving the `fill` above `drawRect`

[image]

Comment: So, the "problem" seems to be with `g2.create(10, 10, 290, 290)` and `graphicsBox.getClipBounds()`.  The first is creating and "translated and clipped" context, BUT, it's taking into account the original `clip` of the parent context, or as the docs say, *"Its clip area is determined by the intersection of the original clip area with the specified rectangle"* .  You then draw a new rectangle WITHIN these bounds, but, because of the clip, it's not clearing the old one

Comment: Now, if you swap the `drawRect` and `fill` commands for `graphicsBox` (and adjust the `drawRect` to take into consideration the line width), you can get a nice square around it.  Now, having said all that, personally, I'd just not use `getClipBounds` this way, and instead, it "should" be used to determine if you actually need to take action at all (don't paint anything outside of the `clipBounds` if you don't have to)

Comment: _I'd just not use getClipBounds this way, and instead, it "should" be used to determine if you actually need to take action at all (don't paint anything outside of the clipBounds if you don't have to)_ Ok that's a good advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a couple of "mistakes"

I found this...

```
graphicsBox.drawRect(clipBounds.x, clipBounds.y, clipBounds.width, clipBounds.height);
graphicsBox.setColor(Color.red);
graphicsBox.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(clipBounds.x + 2,
        clipBounds.y + 2,
        clipBounds.width - 2,
        clipBounds.height - 2));
```

to be a little erroneous, which meant when a clip was applied, the background area was not been filled properly.

The call to `super.paintComponent` was filling the clip area with the background color of the component, but `graphicsBox.fill` wasn't filling the entire area, allow part of the background color to be seen.

I also found the result of `Graphics2D#create(int, int, int, int)` to be a little surprising

> The new Graphics object has its origin translated to the specified point (x, y). **Its clip area is determined by the intersection of the original clip area with the specified rectangle**.

*(emphasis added by me)*

I mean, honestly, I shouldn't be surprised, but I've just never used these features before so it took me a little by surprise.

So, I corrected the `graphicsBox` rendering code so that the `fill` will fill the entire clipping area first and THEN the rectangle is drawn (within the bounding rectangle)

```
var graphicsBox = (Graphics2D) g2.create(10, 10, 290, 290);
var clipBounds = graphicsBox.getClipBounds();

graphicsBox.setColor(Color.red);
graphicsBox.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(clipBounds.x,
        clipBounds.y,
        clipBounds.width,
        clipBounds.height));

Collections.shuffle(colors);
graphicsBox.setColor(colors.get(0));
graphicsBox.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
graphicsBox.drawRect(clipBounds.x + 1, clipBounds.y + 1, clipBounds.width - 2, clipBounds.height - 2);

graphicsBox.dispose();
```

*nb: The reference to `colors` is just a list of `Color`s which I randomise during the paint process, so I can "see" what's going on*

Another trick might be to change the background color of the component to make it easier to "see" where things are been updated incorrectly.

When you have issues like this, it's really important to reduce the amount of clutter to see if you can narrow down the problem, I took out most of the paint code to figure out all these "little" things which were combining to give you issues.

## Runnable example...

[image: Clippy]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var comp = new MyJPanel();
        var timer = new Timer(2_000, e -> {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(comp::bug);
        });
        timer.start();
        timer.setRepeats(true);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            var frame = new JFrame("Reproducer");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().add(comp);
        });
    }

    private static class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
        
        private List<Color> colors;
        
        public MyJPanel() {
            setSize(600, 600);
            setPreferredSize(getSize());
            colors = Arrays.asList(new Color[] {
               Color.BLACK,
                Color.BLUE,
                Color.CYAN,
                Color.DARK_GRAY,
                Color.GRAY,
                Color.GREEN,
                Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
                Color.MAGENTA,
                Color.ORANGE,
                Color.PINK,
                Color.RED,
                Color.WHITE,
                Color.YELLOW
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            var g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            super.paintComponent(g2);
            g2.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g2.fill(g2.getClip());

            var graphicsBox = (Graphics2D) g2.create(10, 10, 290, 290);
            var clipBounds = graphicsBox.getClipBounds();

            graphicsBox.setColor(Color.red);
            graphicsBox.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(clipBounds.x,
                    clipBounds.y,
                    clipBounds.width,
                    clipBounds.height));
            
            Collections.shuffle(colors);
            graphicsBox.setColor(colors.get(0));
            graphicsBox.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
            graphicsBox.drawRect(clipBounds.x + 1, clipBounds.y + 1, clipBounds.width - 2, clipBounds.height - 2);

            graphicsBox.dispose();

            var graphicsOverlay = (Graphics2D) g2.create(100, 100, 100, 100);
            graphicsOverlay.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            graphicsOverlay.fillOval(10, 10, 60, 60);
            graphicsOverlay.dispose();
        }

        public void bug() {
            getVisibleRect();
            repaint(100, 100, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're having "performance" issues, you might consider using a `BufferedImage` as the primary canvas and update it, then simply paint the image.

Alternatively, it might be time to move over to using [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html), this is going to get you as close to the "metal" as Java/Swing allows

Comment: Interesting. However swaping the `drawRect` / `fill` order, still creates an unwanted border as show in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzGUt.png), because the border is not supposed to be drawn within the red rectangle (and in particular within not within the repaint area). Now as you mentioned, I've learned _the hard way_ that `clipBounds` are not suited for getting the enclosing area that a graphic context can draw to, and as a metter of fact I fixed the issue this way, by relying on my own geometry instead of clipbounds.

Comment: I didn't knew yet about `BufferStrategy`, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Swapping the order won't, in of itself, solve the problem.  What I did was make sure that `fill` filled the entire `clipBounds`, then modified the `draw` ensures the frame is drawing within the bounds of the `clipBounds`, this is where I "solved" the overall issue as was presented

Comment: Sorry if my question wording was lacking. So the issue had wider impacts until I removed the use of clipbounds. If there's several repaint on an area, `JComponent` are using [`RepaintManager.addDirtyRegion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html#addDirtyRegion(javax.swing.JComponent,int,int,int,int) because dirty regions of a component are _unioned_ as the javadoc says. And typically I saw these borders when the mouse was hovering a scrollbars.

Comment: @Brice You also need to be careful with using "dirty areas", you need to make sure that the "previously" occupied area is also updated - seen this mess with people a lot

Comment: Yes indeed, currently the repainted code are fixed _overlays_. But this may be useful to know fort things in movement. Thanks a lot.